Extension problem on one-dimension representation on Abelian groups
I was inspired by an exercise from Algebra:

Let $H$ and $G$ be finite abelian groups, $\varphi:H\to G$ a homomorphism, and $\eta:\hat{G} \to \hat{H}, \rho\mapsto \rho \circ\varphi$ an homomorphism between the character groups. Prove that if $\varphi$ is an injection, then $\eta$ is a surjection.

We can see $H$ as a subgroup of $G$, then for a one-dimensional complex representation of $H$, namely $\chi$, if we can find an extension of $\chi$ to $G$, namely $\chi'$, such that $\chi'$ is a one-dimensional complex representation of $G$, and $\chi'(h)=\chi(h),\forall h\in H$, then we are done.
For finite abelian groups, Let $H=\langle h_1\rangle \oplus \cdots \oplus\langle h_s\rangle$, while all $\langle h_i\rangle$ are $p_i$-group respectively, then we have a decomposition $G=\langle g_1\rangle \oplus \cdots \oplus\langle g_s\rangle \oplus \cdots$, with $\langle h_i\rangle \leq \langle g_i\rangle$ and $\langle g_i\rangle$ are $p_i$-group respectively. then we just need to consider the unit roots.
However, when it comes to the infinite part, I am stucked. An easy example is $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$, by considering maping a Hamel basis and their rational multipies to 1. An interesting view is that $\mathbb{R}$ can be considered as direct product of $\mathbb{Q}$'s.
In summary, my question is,

If $G$ is an infinite Abelian group, $H \leq G$ and $\chi$ is a one-dimensional complex representation of $H$, can $\chi$ be extended to $G$?

Can anyone prove this conjecture or give a counterexample?

The condition that every map from a subgroup $\alpha: H \to C$ can be extended to a map $\alpha': G \to C$ is true if and only if $C$ is a divisible group. In particular, it's true when $C$ is the multiplicative group of the complex numbers.
To prove the if part, applying Zorn's lemma to the partial order of homomorphisms extending $\alpha$, ordered by the extension relation, shows that there's a maximal extension of $\alpha$. It is enough to prove that every homomorphism defined on a proper subgroup of $G$ can be extended, since this means the maximal extension must be defined on $G$. Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$, we want to constuct an extension $\beta: K \to C$ where $H \subsetneq K \subset G$.
To construct the map, pick $x \notin H$ and define $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \oplus H \to G$ by
$$\phi(n,h)=nx+h.$$
Then $K = \operatorname{img} \phi$ is a subgroup of $G$ strictly contains $H$. The kernel of $\phi$ is either trivial or infinite cyclic, generated by $(m,-mx)$ where $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $mx \in H$.
If $\operatorname{ker}\phi$ is trivial, let $c=0$. Otherwise, by divisibility of $C$, there exists $c \in C$ such that $mc = \alpha(mx)$. Define a map $\psi: \mathbb{Z} \oplus H \to C$ by
$$\psi(n,h) = nc+\alpha(h).$$
We clearly have $\operatorname{ker}\phi \subset \operatorname{ker}\psi$, so by the homomorphism theorem, there exists $\beta: K \to C$ such that $\psi = \beta \circ \phi$. It's easy to see that $\beta$ extends $\alpha$. QED.
Sidenote: In category theory, an object with the property above is called an injective object. Hence, your question can be phrased as whether the multiplicative group of complex numbers is injective in the category of abelian groups. It is true since the injective of objects in the category of abelian groups are precisely the divisible groups.

Could you please explain how to apply Zorn's lemma? I do not quite understand. And when $C$ is not a divisible group, can we construct a counterexample?

I edited the the Zorn's lemma part to be more clear. For a counterexample, try $2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$.
